# Using savechanges() inside foreach loop c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this method below that is writing data to two tables in the database. There is a collection I need to write to the database in the foreach section. why saveChanges does not work in each iteration of the loop and is there a better way of doing this?
there is two things... first:the function does not return any thing .... second:the database did not up to date .... when i removed savechange() from the function it has works but with out changing values in database .

```
if (_context.ProductPins.Where(a => a.ProductId == id && a.Status==false).Count() > 0)
        {
            var c = 0;
            var ProductPins = _context.ProductPins.Where(a=>a.Status==false && a.ProductId == id);
            foreach(var item in ProductPins)
            {
                ApplicationUser.Balance = ApplicationUser.Balance - product.BuyingPrice;
                item.Equals(true);
                _context.Statements.Add(new Statement
                {
                    Amount = product.BuyingPrice,
                    RecordDate = DateTime.Now,
                    Destination = false,
                    FromApplicationUserId = _userManager.GetUserId(User),
                    //ToApplicationUserId = nu,
                    BalanceType = BalanceType.currentbalance,
                });

                _context.Update(ApplicationUser);
                _context.Update(item);
                _context.SaveChanges();
                c++;
                if (c > count)
                {
                    break;
                }





            }
```

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework?  I know Dapper allows you to actually do collection based inserts, but that looks like Entity Framework is that correct?

Comment: OP, please specify what you mean by "does not work." Do you get an error? Exception? No error but data is not saved? Data is saved but not correctly? Or does it work to spec but you just don't like the code structure?

Comment: @Greg yes i am using entity framework

Comment: @JohnWu there is two things... first:the function does not return any thing .... second:the database did not up to date   .... when i removed savechange() from the function it has works but with out changing values in database

Comment: @محمدالعاني - if you're running sql server as backend, could you check using sql profiler? SaveChanges() should return int showing number of records saved. (on side note, you can change _context.ProductPins.Where(a => a.ProductId == id && a.Status==false).Count() > 0 to _context.ProductPins.Any(a => a.ProductId == id && a.Status==false) and put _userManager.GetUserId(User) outside of the loop).

Comment: Just a suggestion unrelated to question. If you are saving to a database, shouldn't you queue these changes so that you can do one write at the end and process all of them at once rather than one at a time?

Comment: @Slipoch thanks your suggestion solve this issue...if you want change your comment to answer ...and i will give you the best answer...for advantage of this society

Comment: another side note, if your main condition to enter this block is to see if there are applicable records, consider .Any() instead of .Where().Count. As I understand it, where will actually go get records and then count them. Any is the equivalent of 'exists' which is much much faster. Your new condition would be...

if (_context.ProductPins.Any(a => a.ProductId == id && a.Status==false))

Comment: @kd345205 great notice i will  apply it ...thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are saving to a database, you should queue these changes so that you can do one write at the end and process all of them at once rather than one at a time, this way you take advantage of the databases internal write processing.

Answer (score 0):

I only put savechange() method out of froreach loop....savechanges() should be not inside loop

```
if (_context.ProductPins.Where(a => a.ProductId == id && a.Status==false).Count() > 0)
        {
            var c = 0;
            var ProductPins = _context.ProductPins.Where(a=>a.Status==false && a.ProductId == id);
            foreach(var item in ProductPins)
            {
                ApplicationUser.Balance = ApplicationUser.Balance - product.BuyingPrice;
                item.Equals(true);
                _context.Statements.Add(new Statement
                {
                    Amount = product.BuyingPrice,
                    RecordDate = DateTime.Now,
                    Destination = false,
                    FromApplicationUserId = _userManager.GetUserId(User),
                    //ToApplicationUserId = nu,
                    BalanceType = BalanceType.currentbalance,
                });

                _context.Update(ApplicationUser);
                _context.Update(item);

                c++;
                if (c > count)
                {
                    break;
                }





            }
_context.SaveChanges();
```